# Fetching (Near) Real-time data from new database entry

Tags: php, database, real-time, comet

I am currently back to my drawing board after I managed to build a SMS recording system which comprised of a test lab SMSC which has a PHP script to insert/record the SMS received at the SMSC to a MySQL server database, which has the following table format (Sorry for the untidy lines):

|--------------|-------------|---------|
|   Msgid       | Phoneno  |  Msg     |
|--------------|-------------|---------|
|     1              |  12345      | Hello  |
|        2              |  38746      | World  |
|        3              |  16375      | Test     |
|        .               |  .....           | ...          |
|        .               |  .....           | ...          |
|   (autogen)    |  .....           | ...          |
|--------------|-------------|----------|

Now I would like to extend this SMS recording system to a new level - which will be able to **automatically display** the new incoming SMS message to my existing website (which is in PHP as well); **INSTEAD of** manually refreshing the website which contributed huge page overheads as well as enormous load to the server when the number of visitors increase.

Of course, some research has been done on the web which suggest that AJAX paired with a fixed JS interval (say 5~10 seconds) will do the trick, but this will contribute a lot of redundancies when there is not many new incoming SMS within the day.

Besides that, long-polling AJAX should do the trick, which however will consume a thread for the set Interval that reduces the system efficiency as well.

So basically, Comet is one of the options but it is not recommended to be implemented on a PHP platform.

Therefore, are there any inputs/thoughts/suggestions for my idea which is currently on the drawing board?

P/S: Do I really have to go for node.js? Because I don't prefer to have hosted-JS like jQuery but instead write my own function - Given that if it is easy enough! =)

Answer (score 1):

Node.js has become almost synonymous with realtime frameworks, but there are solutions for other technologies. For a PHP solution you could take a look at [Ratchet](http://socketo.me). You can find a more detailed list with other languages on a [realtime web tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) that I'm curating.

If you'd rather offload the persistent connections between client and server then you could look at a realtime hosted service such as [Pusher](http://pusher.com), who I work for. If you were to do that you could:

### Add the library to your HTML and connect to Pusher

```
<script src="http://js.pusher.com/1.12/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var pusher = new Pusher( 'YOUR_APP_KEY' );
  // Additional JavaScript - see below
</script>
```

### Subscribe to a SMS channel

```
var smsChannel = pusher.subscribe( 'sms' );
```

### Bind to an event on the channel for incoming SMS messages

```
smsChannel.bind( 'incoming', function(){} );
```

### Handle the event and update your app as required

```
smsChannel.bind( 'incoming', function( smsData ) {
  var phoneNo = smsData[ 'PhoneNo' ];
  var msg = smsData[ 'Msg' ];
  // Update the UI as required.
} );
```

On the server you need to make a call to Pusher after you've updated your database.

### Include the Pusher library

```
// See: http://pusher.com/docs/server_libraries#php
require('Pusher.php');
```

### Handle the request to your PHP script

```
// I've had to guess a bit here. Hopefully you can convert this to something which meets your requirements/data structures 
$update = $_POST['sms_data'];

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO updates (Phoneno, Msg) VALUES ('%s', '%s')",
  mysql_real_escape_string( $update['Phoneno'], $update['Msg'] ) );

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result) {
  // trigger event
}
```

### Trigger the event

```
if( $result ) {
  // Use key, secret and id defined from config somewhere
  $pusher = new Pusher( PUSHER_APP_KEY, PUSHER_APP_SECRET, PUSHER_APP_ID);
  $data = array( 'Phoneno' => $update['Phoneno'], 'Msg' => $update['Msg'] );
  $pusher->trigger( 'sms', 'incoming', $data );
}
```

Although this example uses Pusher you will be able to follow a similar pattern with other realtime web technologies.

If you want to use a self-hosted option you need to manage the resource used up by the persistent connections that let the server instantly inform the client of the new SMS. If you use a hosted service then you don't need to worry about this.

I also wrote a tutorial about using Pusher and [Twilio](http://twilio.com) that does something very similar to what you are trying to achieve here. The code is in Ruby though. See:
http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/07/pusher-and-twilio-making-realtime-fuctionality-easy.html

Comment: Hi leggetter, many thanks for your long response with regard to Pusher.com. However, as I have mentioned before that I would try to avoid hosted-JS as much because I try to let my server be independent of other party, mainly due to my personal phobia against downtime beyond my control.

Comment: Hi @ChristyW - I tried to make it clear that although the example used Pusher the patterns you follow will be the same for other self-hosted options such as Ratchet. If you use a self-hosted (WebSocket) solution and you have an existing LAMP stack then you'll need to communicate between the two. See: http://socketo.me/docs/push. As per my first para I think Ratchet is the best self-hosted PHP solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand the problem and analyzed that you want to opt for AJAX method but you are afraid of redundancies in case if new incoming messages not arrived much, what I can suggest is:

Split your task in two parts, one task should check new message arrived or not.

and run second task of refreshing window if first task gets true.

In this way it will decrease redundancies.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I think it is becoming too vague to understand what you are trying to say here... Any specific technology can be shared for that specific purpose?

Comment: You can also use extJS for your purpose and if you do not want to use any hosted technology, go for JavaScript and Ajax with your own techniques, using in this project